# How to use a specific version of composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

I am using a shared host which comes with an old version of composer. Unfortunately, it's an old version its not able to install something properly. My shared host provider said I can simply install a new version to my shared root directory.

So I did that by adding a php.ini file and then running the following command

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -c php.ini
```

That seemed to work and when I run the command to check the version it only shows me the new version when I run `php composer.phar -V`. But when I run `composer -V`, it shows me the old version.

How can I override the main composer for my shared directory? And by the way, I did this in my root directory as I have multiple domains so was hoping I could get this to work in all domains.

Comment: you do not need to override the "global" composer. Just use the one in your local directory by running `php composer.phar`, the way you are doing it. There is no reason to override it. But if you really need to, just rename the phar file and make it executable (`mv composer.phar somedir/composer && chmod 755 somedir/composer`), and then change your path variable so that `somedir` comes first. How to do the latter is a linux/ubuntu question, not a composer-php question.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution. I just needed to create an alias and it seems to be working now

```
echo alias composer="composer.phar" >> .bashrc
```

Comment: Thank you. I was in a subdirectory so needed `~/.bashrc`

Comment: For future reference, you can substitute `composer.phar` for the path to the file, like `~/public_html/some_directory/composer.phar`